# Find general matrix $X$ such that $AX=XA$

Tags: matrices

I have this question:

> In general, the matrix multiplication is not commutative. Suppose that the matrix $A = (a_{ij})_{2\times2}$ is in the form:

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\-1&0\\\end{bmatrix}
$$

> Find the general matrix $X = (x_{ij})_{2\times2}$ such that

$$ AX=XA $$

So, in this case, is the vector $X$ simply the same as the vector $A$? or is vector $X$ the same as vector $A$ multiplied by vector $A$ (which comes out to be just vector $A$)? Or is it not that simple and it requires me to work it out?

Comment: It has already given you a hint. Suppose that $X = \begin{bmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} \\ x_{21} & x_{22} \end{bmatrix}$ and solve the equations you obtain by setting $AX=XA$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{bmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} \\ x_{21} & x_{22} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1& 0 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1& 0 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} \\ x_{21} & x_{22} \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} x_{11}-x_{12} & 0 \\ x_{21}-x_{22} & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} \\ -x_{11} & -x_{12} \end{bmatrix}$$

$$x_{11}-x_{12}=x_{11} \implies x_{12} =0$$
$$x_{21}-x_{22}=-x_{11} \implies x_{21}=x_{22}-x_{11}$$

This tells us that knowing $x_{11}$ and $x_{22}$ is sufficient for determining $X$. Suppose that $x_{11} = a$ and $x_{22}=b$:

$$X = \begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ b-a & b \end{bmatrix}$$

is the general solution for any $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. If the matrix $X$ is not of this form, $A$ and $X$ won't commute with each other.

Comment: so $A$ will not commute with identity matrix ?

Comment: @zwim xD Wait. I have made a calculation mistake obviously. :D

Comment: @zwim I fixed it. Solving a problem while you're typing it in LaTeX is prone to calculation mistakes. All those LaTeX codes make it difficult to find your mistakes when you're typing it. :P